# Returning a database with locations

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I think I have the right idea to solve this function, but I'm not sure why I get this error when I test it. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Error: conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Desired Output:

```
  >>> get_locations(db, 'ANTA01H3F')
```

[('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC01', 'AA112'), ('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC01', 'SY110'), ('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC02', 'AC223')]

```
def get_locations(db, course):
'''Return the course, section and locations of the exam for the given course.'''
return run_query('''SELECT Courses.Course, Courses.Sections, Room.Locations 
FROM Courses JOIN Locations ON Courses.ID = Locations.ID WHERE Course = ?''', [course])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too much abstract. ;)

See run_query() from where it is getting the value of db (sqlite database file name) to run queries. It is not getting correct file name that you are expecting.

You are calling the function wrong, it accepts db and sql statement string:

```
return run_query(db, "SELECT Courses.Course, Courses.Sections, Locations.Room " \
 " FROM Courses JOIN Locations ON Courses.ID = Locations.ID WHERE Course = '{}'".format(course))
```

Comment: My run_query function works fine, I was calling it but i don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: def run_query(db, q, args=None):
    """(str, str, tuple) -> list of tuple
    Return the results of running query q with arguments args on
    database db."""

    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # execute the query with the given args passed
    # if args is None, we have only a query
    if args is None:
        cur.execute(q)
    else:
        cur.execute(q, args)

    results = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return results

Comment: Then you are passing the arguments wrong. Let me correct it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ''' instead of ''? Also, I get this error now cur.execute(q)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Room.Locations

Comment: You need to correct your SQL as well. "Room" table/alias is not defined in SQL. What is the column you need from Locations table?

Comment: Room is the column I need from Locations table.

Comment: Then replace Room.Locations with Locations.Room.

Comment: Just one more question. What does {} mean?

Comment: It is a placeholder for the input arguments inside format() function

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: The code itself is an example, the value of course variable replaces {}.